# How to test CSS hover in Enzyme - React

Tags: css, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am new To React testing with Enzyme and Jest, and I have this scenario to test:

When hover the ParentDiv, The Child div should change style to `background-color: green` and `display: block`. 
But in testing, after simulate `mouseenter` event, none of the style is changed, they still `background-color: red` and `display: none`

This is a Class-based component

```
const Child = styled.div`
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
`;

const ParentDiv = styled.div`
    &:hover {
        ${Child} {
            background-color: green;
            display: block;
        }
    }
`;

<ParentDiv>
  <Child>
    <p>{text}</p>
  </Child>
</ParentDiv>
```

Test.js

```
it('Hover over ParentDiv should display the child', () => {
        const Wrapper = mount(<MyComponent >);
        const parent = Wrapper.find('ParentDiv');
        const child = Wrapper.find('child');

        expect(child).toHaveStyleRule('display', 'none');
        expect(child).toHaveStyleRule('background-color', 'red');
        parent.simulate('mouseenter');
        // next two lines not working
        // expect(child).toHaveStyleRule('display', 'block');  // expected display: block but received display: none
        // expect(child).toHaveStyleRule('background-color', 'green');
    });
```

Comment: Are you using mount or shallow to render the component? Is it class based or functional?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: have you found solution on this? @asmaa

Comment: Unfortunately no!

Comment: i also struggle to find solution for this

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone comes looking, the solution for this is to use the `opts` parameter in `toHaveStyleRule`.

so you need to use this:

`expect(child).toHaveStyleRule('display', 'block', { modifier: ':hover' });`

Here is a link to the docs: https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components#tohavestylerule